# Why are some installers insisting on using IE?

Tags: browser, windows-installer

When you install some software, there is sometimes a link you can click on that takes you to the developers website, and some installers will persistently open this link in IE, even when it's not the default web browser.

Why are they insisting on using IE (Internet Explorer)? If I set Firefox to be my default web browser, why is this fact being ignored? And how do they achieve this?

The same applies to some applications.

Comment: You should ask the guys writing those installers. Related question: how many programs do you know that respect your localization settings (date format, number format, ...)? If a program is not respecting the users customization, then either the developer was lazy/does not mind or did not know how to do it right. Just want you to remind of software that still requires admin rights to run - 17 years after Windows NT 4.0. How could developers argue that they still don't do it right?

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. They had 17 years to learn how to do it properly, right? But at least I now know that it's the developers fault, and not Windows fault. I will ask the developer of this **paid software** why they are not respecting users' customization settings.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type:

```
iexplore http://superuser.com/
```

Now press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and... that's how they do this ;)

There are two reliable ways to open links, one is by running `http://example.com` (system will handle it with default browser) and second one is by running `iexplore http://example.com` (it will run IE's executable and pass it a command line argument with the URL). For some unknown reasons some developers use that second method.

Comment: So they have this line embedded somewhere in the code? Is there a way around it?...

Comment: @Sammy Not sure if I should actually recommend that, but you could remap `iexplore` (%path%, overwrite the executable, ...). Use at your own risk.

Comment: @JanDvorak Can you be more specific? Where do I make that change?

Comment: @Sammy overwriting the iexplore.exe file is easy but that's not what I'd like to suggest. I can't help much concerning how you should edit the path, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is they achieve it by calling `iexplore.exe` directly rather than the system defined browser.

As to why, that is more of a philosophical question. The simple answer is because the developers are lazy. There are certain "features" of IE that are not standard and will not work with other browsers. Part of Microsoft's long standing campaign to force people to use IE. Good developers work around it, lazy ones will force you to use IE.

Comment: Are you talking about websites or about desktop applications? I cannot picture how `navigator.userAgent` and browser detection while surfing the web is relevant here.

Comment: I remember the time when IE used to be the only web browser. I remember the time when Firefox, Opera, and other browsers became relevant which sparked the browser wars, and the many iterations of IE based web browsers. But now days it is supposed to be pretty straight forward to use any browser, and even Microsoft is getting used to being more open. That's why I'm so surprised to see that some applications still enforce IE one way or another.

Comment: We should ban this kind of behavior and pass on laws that will enforce penalties toward developers who program their software to only use IE. Something similar has already been brought forward against Microsoft by the European Commission. Unfortunately these thugs and outlaws don't know any other way of doing business. You have to force them to abide by certain principles. Freedom of browser choice is the equivalent of freedom of speech in the digital world.

Comment: @Sammy, there was _never_ ever a time when IE was the only browser and the browser wars predate firefox.

Comment: I know Mosaic and Netscape predate IE, but as far as I know IE was the only and still is the only browser bundled with Windows. There have been more than one browser war over the years. IE was first bundled with Windows 95. Prior to Windows 95, how did Windows users even get Netscape installed? Was it distributed on floppy disks? I mean without a browser you can't download anything from the web. I remember using IE to download Netscape.

Comment: Even now, the first thing I do after installing Windows is to use IE to download Firefox, or Chrome or whichever.

Comment: @Sammy, you're quite right, the `navigator.userAgent` is irrelevant, I had misunderstood. As for downloading, a browser is only essential to view HTML. FTP,SSH,telnet etc are perfectly suited for downloading. And yes, software was distributed on floppies as well. I remember having to go through a huge stack of the things to install Windows 95 itself. Anyway, [browser wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_wars) was first used about the "battle" between Netscape and IE, long before firefox. And don't forget that not everyone uses windows, I for example, have not done so since the late 90s.

Comment: Are you using Linux? How was Netscape Navigator 1.0 downloaded back in 1994? If you were a Windows 3.1 user? Do you know? Maybe with a FTP client? And what about Linux, was Linux ever bundled with the early Netscape browser?

Comment: It was probably most often downloaded through telnet but I'm not sure. As for Linux, yes some distributions came with netscape pre-installed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9076/discussion-between-sammy-and-terdon)